# Display foreign key records on a new page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have this table of trucks.

```
<div class="myform">
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Plate Number</th>
        </tr>
        <?php do { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo strtoupper($row_Trucks['truck_plate_no']); ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_Trucks = mysql_fetch_assoc($Trucks)); ?>
      </table>

    </form>
</div>
```

and this list of trucks is related to a delivery details table

```
tbl_delivery_details, tbl_po, tbl_waybill, tbl_fuel_details, tbl_driver...
```

and also connected to a bunch of other tables in the database. How can i display the records related to each of the trucks when i click the truck plate number on the table and link me to another page that will show me all the records related to that truck, the truck table is a foreign key on the other tables.

Comment: pass the ID in a link through the query string and on the page you link  to, run a query in the DB with that ID value and display the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
If `truck_plate_number` is unique,you can pass it along with the link as shown below.Otherwise,get the ID of record(primary key) and replace the `$truck_plate_no` with that ID in the below code.

```
<div class="myform">
        <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>Plate Number</th>
        </tr>
                <?php do {
        $truck_plate_no=$row_Trucks['truck_plate_no'];
        echo '<tr><td><a href=anotherpage.php?truck_plate_no='.$truck_plate_no.'>'.strtoupper($truck_plate_no).'</td></tr>';

               } while ($row_Trucks = mysql_fetch_assoc($Trucks));
              ?>
              </table>
```

**In anotherpage.php**

```
<?php  
$truck_plate_number=$_GET['truck_plate_no'];//get value from url

?>
```

Then query, details from the table using this id.